# Monitor.Wait, Condition variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

Given a following code snippet(found in somewhere while learning threading).

```
 public class BlockingQueue<T>
    {
        private readonly object sync = new object();
        private readonly Queue<T> queue;
        public BlockingQueue()
        {
            queue = new Queue<T>();
        }

        public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(item);
                Monitor.PulseAll(sync);
            }

        }
        public T Dequeue()
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                while (queue.Count == 0)
                    Monitor.Wait(sync);

                return queue.Dequeue();
            }

        }
    }
```

What I want to understand is ,

**Why is there a while loop ?**

```
   while (queue.Count == 0)
            Monitor.Wait(sync);
```

**and what is wrong with the,**

```
 if(queue.Count == 0)
       Monitor.Wait(sync);
```

In fact, all the time when I see the similar code I found using while loop, can anyone please help me understand the use of one above another.
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to specify language and add appropriate tag.

Comment: Forgot that, someone already added C# tag.

Comment: It is to do with Hoare semantics vs Mesa Semantics [Mesa scheduling]. In general you have to use loops with Mesa scheduling. But in your special case it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to understand what `Pulse`, `PulseAll`, and `Wait` are doing. The `Monitor` maintains two queues: the waiting queue and the ready queue. When a thread calls `Wait` it is moved into the waiting queue. When a thread calls `Pulse` it moves *one and only one* thread from the waiting queue to the ready queue. When a thread calls `PulseAll` it moves *all* threads from the waiting queue to the ready queue. Threads in the ready queue are eligible to reacquire the lock at any moment, but only after the current holder releases it of course.

Based on this knowledge it is fairly easy to understand why you must recheck the queue count when using `PulseAll`. It is because *all* dequeueing threads will eventually wake and will want to attempt to extract an item from queue. But, what if there is only one item in the queue to begin with? Obviously, we must recheck the queue count to avoid dequeueing an empty queue.

So what would be the conclusion if you had used `Pulse` instead of `PulseAll`? There would still be a problem with the simple `if` check. The reason is because a thread from the ready queue is not necessarily going to be the next thread to acquire the lock. That is because the `Monitor` does not give preference to a `Wait` call above an `Enter` call.

The `while` loop is a fairly standard pattern when using `Monitor.Wait`. This is because pulsing a thread does not have semantic meaning by itself. It is only a signal that the lock state has changed. When threads wake up after blocking on `Wait` they should recheck the same condition that was originally used to block the thread to see if the thread can now proceed. Sometimes it cannot and so it should block some more.

The best rule of thumb here is that if there is doubt about whether to use an `if` check or a `while` check then always choose a `while` loop because it is safer. In fact, I would take this to the extreme and suggest to *always* use a `while` loop because there is no inherent advantage in using the simpler `if` check and because the `if` check is almost always the wrong choice anyway. A similar rule holds for choosing whether to use `Pulse` or `PulseAll`. If there is doubt about which one to use then always choose `PulseAll`.

Comment: +1 very helpful guide on Monitor usage. Indeed, 'if' without double locking is nothing but a debugging disaster.

Comment: @Brain Gideon. awesome explanation!

Comment: Don't you think the .NET Monitor is flawed in design? There shouldn't be just two queues; there should be more than one waiting queue, each for a particular waiting condition specified by the <lock, condition variable> pair, as what pthreads does. Having a big Waiting queue leads to excessive context switches when one thread wakes up only the find the waiting condition has not changed at all, then immediately going to back to the waiting queue.

Comment: @h9uest: You make a good point. I don't know if I'd go as far as saying it's a flaw, but there are definitely disadvantages with the current design. Could it be better? Probably...yes, but at what cost?

Answer (score 3):

you have to keep checking whether the queue is still empty or not. Using only if would only check it once, wait for a while, then a dequeue. What if at that time the queue is still empty? BANG! queue underflow error...

Comment: But a Wait only wakes up after a Pulse, and that happens when something is Enqueued.

Answer (score 1):

with **if** condition when something released the lock the **queue.Count == 0** will not check again and maybe a queue underflow error so we have to check the condition every time because of concurrency and this is called **Spinning**

Answer (score 0):

Why on Unix it could go wrong is because of the spurious wake up, possibility caused by OS signals. It is a side effect that is not guaranteed to never happen on windows as well. This is not a legacy, it is how OS works. If Monitors are implemented in terms of Condition Variable, that is.

def : a *spurious wake up* is a re-scheduling of a sleeping thread on a condition variable wait site, that was not triggered by an action coming from the current program threads (like `Pulse()`).

This inconvenience could be masked in managed languages by, e.g. the queues. So before going out of the `Wait()` function, the framework could check that this running thread is actually really being requested for scheduling, if it does not find itself in a run queue it can go back to sleep. Hiding the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (queue.Count == 0)
```

will do.

Using while loop pattern for "wait for and check condition" context is a legacy leftover, I think. Because non-Windows, non-.NET monitor variables can be triggered without actual `Pulse`.

In .NET, you private monitor variable cannot be triggered without `Queue` filling so you don't need to worry about queue underflow after monitor waiting. But, it is really not bad habit to use while loop for "wait for and check condition".

Comment: Sounds very complex to me, can you please point to some resource where I can understand what you mean.

Comment: Well.. I'm afraid I cannot provide more detailed resource about this. This is from my own experience. I have used 'if ..' coding many years in Windows and had no problem. When I used 'if ..' coding in Linux? all messed up. You required to use while loop for monitor (condition) variables in *Nix platform. After that I always use while loop regardless language/platform.

Comment: IMHO a simple `if` won't do. You could run into a race condition if another thread `Dequeues` in the meantime. I suspect it depends on whether `PulseAll` or just `Pulse` is called...

Comment: Even if `Pulse` were used there would still be a problem with the simple `if` check.

Comment: multiple threads can't execute 'if ...' code because of previous lock(sync) statement.