# FIFO Queue is causing IIS processor to max out at 100%

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, queue, fifo

I have a singleton service class on IIS as part of a web application (the service to be a singleton for data caching reasons). Browser clients that make requests to the service can have one of three results:

1) There is data in the cache and the data is not expired (stale) - we return this data. Very fast. 
2) The cached data is expired, but another request is already querying the database. We returned the cached data. 
3) The cached data is expired and no requests are making queries to the DB. This request moves forward to make the query.

However, database queries that target stored procedures with the same name have to be queued (requirement).

Thus, I wrote this queue class that is designed to queue these queries and run them consecutively, instead of concurrently. These queue classes are created as needed and stored in a list in the singleton class. When a request moves to part (3), it finds the queue class that matches its stored procedure name and submits the request to the queue class. It then waits until the data is returned from the DB so it can service the HTML request.

Unfortunately, after a few hours with this code in place, the server process maxes at 100%.

I am not sure what the best way is to go about improving it, because multi-thrread coding is not my specialty.

The queue class code looks like this:

```
public ReportTable GetReportTable(ReportQuery query)
{
  lock (_queue)
  {
    _queue.Enqueue(query);
    Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
  }

  lock (_queue)
  {
    var firstQueryInQueue = _queue.Peek();
    while (_inUse || firstQueryInQueue == null || firstQueryInQueue.GetHashCode() != query.GetHashCode())
    {
      Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
      Monitor.Wait(_queue);
    }

    _inUse = true;
    firstQueryInQueue = _queue.Dequeue();
    var table = firstQueryInQueue.GetNewReportTable();
    _inUse = false;

    Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
    return table;
  }
}
```

Comment: Starting in .NET 4.0, there's already a `ConcurrentQueue` written for you in the framework: ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) ) Can you use that?

Comment: I tried using that at one point Nicholas, but it didn't seem to really fit my situation. Queuing items is easy enough. It's getting the calling threads to wait without chewing up processor time that's the issue.

Comment: Writing a concurrent queue is hard to get right, as you have found. I suggest you try to use the framework implementation if you can. If  you want to learn more about using `Monitor` correctly, I wrote an article you might like to read : [Wait and Pulse demystified](http://simplygenius.net/Article/WaitPulse)

Comment: @ChrisHolmes - OK, use BlockingCollection instead.

Comment: I do not think a BlockingCollection solves my problem Martin. Maybe I misunderstand the documentation I've read about it. But in my particular case, the threads calling into this method are the same threads that have to wait AND consume. A single thread calling into this method has to (1) enqueue its item (2) wait until its item finds its way to the front of the queue (3) dequeue its item and do work. What I need to do is have each calling thread wait without chewing up processor time. What I'm trying to do here is take concurrent calls and make them serial without slamming the processor.

Comment: Because the stored proc invocation is inside the lock statement, nothing gets queued while the stored proc is executing. The proc is blocking the calling thread and the other threads are blocked by the lock statements. Might be worth trying to have the stored proc invocation outside of the lock statements, as they are already protected by the _inUse flags.

Comment: @ChrisHolmes - I have a couple of questions. 1) Why use a Monitor here instead of a ManualResetEvent? Is something supposed to be going on in the background while this is refreshing? 2) Why does this function enter and exit critical sections in sequence? I guess I'm missing the overall picture here. Do you have a self-contained sample here? I suspect that over time you are kicking off more and more threads that are doing work without ever completing and updating your cache, but it's hard to tell from this snippet.

Comment: I chose Monitor because it made more sense to me. As for overall picture: These are web requests into a singleton service on IIS. Each web request can (and probably will) take place on a separate thread. To the request - everything needs to be sequential. The issue is, these separate threads can make concurrent, threaded requests to the DB and we don't want that. So we have to queue the requests to the DB, yet maintain each thread's desire to serve a response. The threads need to wait their turn without chewing up clock cycles.

Comment: I managed to fix the code and the server ran all day without issue. There were a few spikes in CPU, but I attest that to normal load. For the most part, the server ran 1% to 5% all day. I'll post updated code shortly as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did to fix it.

```
public ReportTable GetReportTable(ReportQuery query)
{
  lock (_queue)
  {
    _queue.Enqueue(query);
    Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
  }

  lock (_queue)
  {
    var firstQueryInQueue = _queue.Peek();
    while (_inUse || firstQueryInQueue == null || firstQueryInQueue.GetHashCode() != query.GetHashCode())
    {
      Monitor.Wait(_queue);
    }

    _inUse = true;
    firstQueryInQueue = _queue.Dequeue();
    var table = firstQueryInQueue.GetNewReportTable();
    _inUse = false;

    Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
    return table;
  }
}
```

The reason it didn't work before was because of my lack of total understanding of Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse(). I was using Pulse() in a wrong place in the code. Fortunately, there's a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327278/monitor-wait-condition-variable) that goes on to describe Wait() and Pulse() quite well.

The key is to Pulse() after the collection is changed, and give the subsequent queued threads a chance to test for the condition, which is: Is my query first in the queue? And is someone else already making a query? Failing that test, the thread calls Wait(), which puts it in the wait queue, and it doesn't tie up processor cycles. When the thread that *is* in the front and is performing the query completes, it flips the _inUse flag to false and calls Pulse(), waking one of the next threads so it can check the condition.

After implementing this solution and watching the Task Manager for a day, I was happy to see 1% to 5% load on the server for several hours, and the CPU never climbed to 100% as before.

I've done a lot of reading on this and it seems that PulseAll() might be the better call in this scenario, but so far Pulse() is working and we haven't encountered any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand problem
but u can rewrite it very simply

```
private object _lockObj=new object();
public ReportTable GetReportTable(ReportQuery query)
{
  lock(_lockObj){
    var table = query.GetNewReportTable();
    return table;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting, about your answer: when you rely on only lock, it is my understanding that it will cause the current thread to spinwait for a while, before finally being pushed into a wait state. During that spinwait time, it's chewing cpu cycles. I need the most efficient solution possible. My very first solution was actually similar to yours, and resulting in the CPU maxing out at 100% after a few minutes with this application running. That's what I'm trying to avoid by using a slightly more complex solution.

Comment: but you have already use lock. consider situation that two request reach your second lock then one of them lock just how my code work